# <command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers ........ Solution for this error?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to interface **ssd1963 LCD with Raspberry Pi3 model B+**, by following this guide on `Github`.

> https://github.com/matusnovak/rpi-tftgl

While trying to install the `makefile` provided for `rpi-tftgl` in `rpi-tftgl/tftgl` directory I am getting this error when I run `make` command. 
Here is the link of my captured image of pi terminal window showing the exact error:

[image]

Following is the error i recieved when I execute `make` command :

```
gcc -c src/tftgl.c -o src/tftgl.o -I/opt/vc/include -I. -Iinclude -D:0 -O3
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'src/tftgl.o' failed
make: *** [src/tftgl.o] Error 1
```

Can I get a solution for this or any recommendation for any other source or links which I can follow to interface ssd1963 LCD with touch enabled with Raspberrypi3.
Adding the makefile,

```
 CC=gcc
 AR=ar
 DISPLAY?=ERROR
 CFLAGS=-I/opt/vc/include -I. -Iinclude -D$(DISPLAY) -O3
 prefix?=/usr/local

 .PHONY: default all clean

  default: tftgl
  all: default

  tftgl: libtftgl.a

  libtftgl.a: src/tftgl.o
     $(AR) rcs libtftgl.a src/tftgl.o

  src/tftgl.o: src/tftgl.c src/tftgl_ssd1963.h src/tftgl_ads7843.h
     $(CC) -c src/tftgl.c -o src/tftgl.o $(CFLAGS)

  install: tftgl
     install -m 0755 libtftgl.a $(prefix)/lib
     install -m 0644 include/tftgl.h $(prefix)/include

  clean:
     -rm -f src/*.o
     -rm -f libtftgl.a
```

I am providing here link to tftgl.c, 
**https://github.com/matusnovak/rpi-tftgl/blob/master/tftgl/src/tftgl.c**

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Comment: `-D0:0` is incorrect. To say more we need to see the relevant portion of the Makefile and possibly the configure script. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jww I have added the makefile in the codeblock, however I don't have any idea from where to get the configure script. Can you say something with it so that I also understand whatnext I have to do. Please help me learn

Comment: The display define should probably be something like `CFLAGS=... -DDISPLAY="$(DISPLAY)"` (possibly with some extra hoops to preserve the quotes). It is just a guess though. We need to see how it is being used in `src/tftgl.c`.

Comment: @jww  I tried changing the makefile with what you suggested and recieved the following error,
gcc -c src/tftgl.c -o src/tftgl.o -I/opt/vc/include -I. -Iinclude --DDISPLAY=":0"
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--DDISPLAY=:0’
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'src/tftgl.o' failed
make: *** [src/tftgl.o] Error 1

Comment: @jww Please could you look at the tftgl.c file and teach me where possibly it is going wrong and how to solve it, because I found no other tutorial for interfacing ssd1963 with pi, as i am bound by the hardware specified can't use any other LCD even. 
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (writer of) the `Makefile` doesn't take into account that the environment variable `DISPLAY` can be defined to something else than a macro definition. As it's not documented whether and how you'd need to define it, the best you can do is to `make` with the variable unset:

```
(unset DISPLAY; make)
```

If you prefer to change the makefile, just remove the `?` from `DISPLAY?=ERROR`, leaving `DISPLAY=ERROR`.

Comment: sir should I make this change in the makefile as.     -D$(unset DISPLAY) -O3 or where DISPLAY is defined as here. unset DISPLAY?=ERROR

Comment: @Shreyansh Dubey - This change is to be used on the terminal command line where you start `make`. I amended the answer with an alternative change in the makefile.

Comment: Thankyou I shall try it